# Classify if point is within specified area using threshold - python

Tags: python, pandas, classification

I've got a df that contains xy points. I want to remove these points if they are located within a polygon for those frames only. This is exhibited as `area` below. The points will come and go from this area, so I only want to remove when they are definitively placed within there. Otherwise keep them in the df.

The central dilemma is I don't want to pass a strict rule here. Because the points are fluid, I'm hoping to incorporate flexibility. For instance, some points may pass through this area temporarily and shouldn't be removed. While other points are located within the area long enough that they should be removed.

The obvious approach is to pass some method of threshold here. Using `df1` below, `A` is located within the area for 3 frames, while `B` is located within the area for 7 frames. If I pass a threshold of >5 frames, `B` should be removed for the frames within this area, while `A` shouldn't be impacted.

The issue is, it has to be consecutive frames. The points will come and go, so I only want to remove after 5 consecutive frames.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X' : [-5,10,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,30,20,10,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,5],  
    'Y' : [50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50],                  
    'Label' : ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'], 
    'Time' : [501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,511],                         
    })

# designated area
x = ([1.5,-0.5,-1.25,-0.5,1.5,-11,-11,1.5]) 
y = ([75,62.5,50,37.5,25,25,75,75])

area = mpltPath.Path([[x, y] for x, y in zip(x, y)])
df1['is_inside'] = area.contains_points(df1[['X','Y']])
```

Out:

```
     X   Y Label  Time  is_inside
0   20  50     A   501       True # inside but only 1 frame. Keep
1   10  50     A   502      False # keep
2    0  50     A   503       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
3   -5  50     A   504       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
4   -5  50     A   505       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
5   -5  50     A   506       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
6    0  50     A   507       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
7   10  50     A   508       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
8   20  50     A   509       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
9   30  50     A   510      False # keep
10  20  50     B   501      False # keep
11  10  50     B   502      False # keep
12   0  50     B   503      False # keep
13  -5  50     B   504       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
14  -5  50     B   505       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
15  -5  50     B   506       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
16  -5  50     B   507       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
17  -5  50     B   508       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
18  -5  50     B   509       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
19  -5  50     B   510       True # inside total 7 frames (remove)
20   5  50     B   511      False # keep
```

Intended Output:

```
     X   Y Label  Time 
0   -5  50     A   501     
1   10  50     A   502         
9   30  50     A   510     
10  20  50     B   501     
11  10  50     B   502     
12   0  50     B   503     
20   5  50     B   511
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I start by replicating your data:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib as mpl

x = [1.5, -0.5, -1.25, -0.5, 1.5, -11, -11, 1.5]
y = [75, 62.5, 50, 37.5, 25, 25, 75, 75]
vertices = list(zip(x, y))
polygon = mpl.path.Path(vertices, closed=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X' : [-5, 10, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, 30, 
           20, 10, 0, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, 5],  
    'Y' : [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
           50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50],                  
    'Label' : list('A'*10 + 'B'*11), 
    'Time' : 2*list(range(501, 511)) + [511]
    })
df = df.sort_values(['Label', 'Time'])
df['is_inside'] = polygon.contains_points(df[['X','Y']])
```

This is how the original DataFrame looks:

```py
In [91]: df
Out[91]: 
     X   Y Label  Time  is_inside
0   -5  50     A   501       True
1   10  50     A   502      False
2   -5  50     A   503       True
3   -5  50     A   504       True
4   -5  50     A   505       True
5   -5  50     A   506       True
6   -5  50     A   507       True
7   -5  50     A   508       True
8   -5  50     A   509       True
9   30  50     A   510      False
10  20  50     B   501      False
11  10  50     B   502      False
12   0  50     B   503      False
13  -5  50     B   504       True
14  -5  50     B   505       True
15  -5  50     B   506       True
16  -5  50     B   507       True
17  -5  50     B   508       True
18  -5  50     B   509       True
19  -5  50     B   510       True
20   5  50     B   511      False
```

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to remove the unwanted points:

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

threshold = 5

indexer = []

for label in np.unique(df['Label']):
    for key, group in groupby(df.loc[df['Label'] == label]['is_inside']):
        runlength = len(list(group))
        remove = key and (runlength > threshold)
        indexer.extend([remove]*runlength)

df.drop(df[indexer].index, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```py
In [92]: df
Out[92]: 
     X   Y Label  Time  is_inside
0   -5  50     A   501       True
1   10  50     A   502      False
9   30  50     A   510      False
10  20  50     B   501      False
11  10  50     B   502      False
12   0  50     B   503      False
20   5  50     B   511      False
```

Comment: Thanks. I only want to remove for 5 consecutive frames. Not in total.

Comment: I've edited my answer so that `threshold` now applies to "consecutive times" rather than "total times".

Comment: Thanks for this. If I had numerous `Labels`, would it be more efficient to apply the function with a `groupby` statement or remove the `Label` parameter?

Comment: I don't know. If you have efficiency concerns it might be a good idea to benchmark your code.

Comment: Thanks, maybe the question wasn't clear. I only want to remove the points when they are located within the area for 5 consecutive frames. Otherwise keep them.

Comment: This is exactly what my code does. See my edited answer.

Comment: I only want to remove frames greater than threshold. Otherwise keep them in. You've removed every frame for `B`. Every label will be located within that area at some stage. I only want to remove the frames when above a certain threshold.

Comment: See my intended output for the B label. At time points `501,502,503,511` the label is outside the polygon, so keep these frames.

Comment: I've changed my answer (once again) to meet the new problem specification.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I specified from the beginning. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: My pleasure. I'm glad that in the end I was able to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest (and efficient) approach is to use `pd.DataFrame.groupby`. This also has the added benefit of being able to easily add more polygons/filters for more complicated classifications.

#### DEFINE OBJECTS

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.path as mpltPath
```

Use the same data as the original question

```
# Define data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [20, 10, 0, -5, -5, -5, 0, 10, 20, 30, 20, 10, 0, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5],
    'Y': [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50],
    'Label': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Time': [501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510],
})
```

Define the polygon directly from matplotlib.path.Path object (i.e. no need to plot first).

```
# Define Polygon
x, y = [1.5, -0.5, -1.25, -0.5, 1.5, -11, -11, 1.5], [75, 62.5, 50, 37.5, 25, 25, 75, 75]
path = mpltPath.Path([[x, y] for x, y in zip(x, y)])
df['is_inside'] = path.contains_points(df[['X','Y']])
```

#### ROLLING GROUPBY

Sort because time ordering matters on rolling operations

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Label','Time'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The following function checks whether each label is in polygon for `n` consecutive frames

```
def get_label_to_remove(df, n):
    d = df.groupby(['Label'])['is_inside'].agg(lambda x: x.rolling(n).agg(all).any())
    return d.to_dict()
```

#### TEST CASES

The observations are distributed like the following (1 denotes a point inside the polygon):

```
        501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510
    A   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
    B   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Notice A appears 3 consecutive times and B apperas 7 consecutive times. Observe how the function behaves at `[2,3,4]` and `[6,7,8]`.

```
In[0]:
for n in [2,3,4,6,7,8]:
    print(n, get_label_to_remove(df, n))

Out[0]:
2 {'A': True, 'B': True}
3 {'A': True, 'B': True}
4 {'A': False, 'B': True}
6 {'A': False, 'B': True}
7 {'A': False, 'B': True}
8 {'A': False, 'B': False}
```

This works with any number of labels without any changes.

#### REMOVING ONLY THE BAD POINTS

Adding this at OP's request. The following identify the bad points instead of just the bad labels (use `to_remove` as mask)

```
n = 5
df['to_remove'] = df.groupby(['Label'])['is_inside'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(n).agg(all)).fillna(0).astype(bool)
df.loc[df['is_inside'] & ~df['to_remove'], ['to_remove']] = pd.NA
df['to_remove'] = df['to_remove'].fillna(method='bfill')
```

Quick run

```
In[0]:
df

Out[0]:
0   20  50  A   501 False   False
1   10  50  A   502 False   False
2   0   50  A   503 False   False
3   -5  50  A   504 True    False
4   -5  50  A   505 True    False
5   -5  50  A   506 True    False
6   0   50  A   507 False   False
7   10  50  A   508 False   False
8   20  50  A   509 False   False
9   30  50  A   510 False   False
10  20  50  B   501 False   False
11  10  50  B   502 False   False
12  0   50  B   503 False   False
13  -5  50  B   504 True    True
14  -5  50  B   505 True    True
15  -5  50  B   506 True    True
16  -5  50  B   507 True    True
17  -5  50  B   508 True    True
18  -5  50  B   509 True    True
19  -5  50  B   510 True    True
```

Comment: Thanks. I only want to remove for 5 consecutive frames. Not in total.

Comment: @jonboy the answer works with consecutive frames now - and it should scale pretty well with increasing number of unique labels.

Comment: Thanks. I feel this is close to what I want but not quite. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

### Disclaimer:

This is an extension to the answers posted above. I think both answers above are really good and just want to add my 2 cents instead of reinventing the wheel. So I'm gonna extend Leonardus Chen answers and all credit should go to him.

### Reason why one might want to extend the previous answers

To make you detection **more robust against outlayers**, you could introduce some kind of **smoothing**. (Worst case scenario: 4 out of 5 frames the position is inside the polygon but it just happens to be that on every fifth frame the position is outside for a single frame)

The smoothing could be a simple criteria like "Remove if the position has been inside the polygon for at least 5 out of 8 consecutive frames" or you could go even smoother and use some e.g. gaussian weighting curve.

### Code Base

For this you do as Leonardus Chen does:

```py
### Code copied from Leonardus Chen to create a fully working example
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.path as mpltPath

# Define data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [20, 10, 0, -5, -5, -5, 0, 10, 20, 30, 20, 10, 0, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5],
    'Y': [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50],
    'Label': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Time': [501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510],
})

# Define Polygon
x, y = [1.5, -0.5, -1.25, -0.5, 1.5, -11, -11, 1.5], [75, 62.5, 50, 37.5, 25, 25, 75, 75]
path = mpltPath.Path([[x, y] for x, y in zip(x, y)])
df['is_inside'] = path.contains_points(df[['X','Y']])
```

### Code Extension

#### Approach 1

And now you keep working with `df['is_inside']`.

- First we will calculate the number of `True`s we have by adding `booleans` (as `True` = `1`, `False` = `0`).
- After that we will check if the number is higher that out set limit of 5.
- Make sure to set `min_periods = 1` as otherwise no rolling window will be created for the first `7` entries as the windows are not yet of size `8`.

"Remove if inside 5 out of 8 frames" looks like this:

```py
df['inside_score'] = df['is_inside'].rolling(window=8, min_periods=1).sum()
df['inside_score_critical'] = df['inside_score'] >= 5
```

#### Approach 2

I'm gonna present a similar criteria that uses a gaussian smoothing function instead of a set window size. Unfortunately to create the desired result you have to play around with the numbers.

- Here the `windows` parameter does not matter much but should generally be a lot higher that `std=4` as otherwise a not so smooth cutoff might be noticable.
- Instead set `std=4` to control the width of the gaussian curve to achieve a span that you desire. (I found a std of 4 to behave similar to the approach above while hopefully being a bit smoother)

```py
df['inside_score_2'] = df['is_inside'].rolling(window=10, min_periods=1, win_type='gaussian').sum(std=4)
df['inside_score_2_critical'] = df['inside_score_2'] >= 5
```